# How to get ftype for the current user

Tags: xml

I have set the current users default program for type .xmlFile to Internet Explorer and the icon for IE shows next to .xml files.

When I use `ftype` to find default app it still shows `MSOXMLED.EXE`?

How can I find the default app for the local user?

I want to check this using my program to make sure it is set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem when running Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator:

[image]

However, this has absolutely no effect upon the execution of `.xml` files.
Only when in File Explorer I did a right-click on an `.xml` file and used
"Open with...", did this make a difference.

The registry entry that really affects execution is found in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.xml\UserChoice
```

It looks like this for IE:

[image]

Comment: The next question is how do I get hold of that UserChoice/Progid by calling some system function?? RegQueryValueEx??

Comment: Yes, for a program that can call that API. Or you may use PowerShell. Or in a `.bat` file you could use [reg query](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query) to get the value into a local environment variable with this [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359239/165358).

Comment: Yes that was very useful. I eventually used RegQueryValueEx

Comment: key:= 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.xml\UserChoice';
           ss:=ReadRegStr(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Key, 'Progid');